# Null Reference Error when directly assigning a List object to an PagedList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, nullreferenceexception, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, pagedlist

KeyMaster Model

```
        public class KeyMasterModel
        {   
            public int KeyId { get; set; }

            public int TypeId { get; set; }

            public string TypeName { get; set;}

        }
```

PagedKeyModel

```
        public class PagedKeyModel
        {
            // Collection of our KeyMasterModel , trying to populate this and send it to ViewModel to display a Grid//

            public IPagedList<Security.Models.KeyMasterModel> pagedkeymaster;
        }
```

//ViewModel//

```
           public class KeyMasterViewModel
        {
```

//tell me how to initialise the KeyMasterViewModel.pagedkeymodel.pagedkeymaster in a constructor here so that I dont get a null

```
            public PagedKeyModel pagedkeymodel;

            public KeyMasterModel keymastermodel;

        }
```

//Controller//

```
                 [HttpGet]
                public ActionResult ListOfKey(string sortOrder, string CurrentSort, int? page)
                {    

// View Model Object //

KeyMasterViewModel keyMasterViewModel = new KeyMasterViewModel();


    // At the gollowing step keyMasterModelObject has values retrieved from db //

//Next aim is to place it into ViewModel Object by assigning the retrieved PagedList of KeyMasterModel to IPagedList<Security.Models.KeyMasterModel> pagedkeymaster


  IPagedList<KeyMasterModel> KeyMasterModelObject= datalayercall.GetAll(sortOrder, CurrentSort, page);

    // Here is where error is thrown , all of a sudden I get the error , KeyMasterModelObject becomes null .

    // I am trying finally to populate everything into ViewModel object

          keyMasterViewModel .pagedkeymodel.pagedkeymaster = KeyMasterModelObject;

          return View(keyMasterViewModel);
        }
```

// Business Logic Layer

```
         public IPagedList<KeyMasterModel> GetAll(string sortOrder, string CurrentSort, int? page)
                {

                    var retrieveddatalayerobject = datalayerobject.KeyMasters;

    // Retrieving Data from db and forming a list according to my model in App//

                    List<KeyMasterModel> keymastermodellist = new List<KeyMasterModel>();

                    KeyMasterModel keymastermodelobject=new KeyMasterModel();

                    foreach(var retrieveditems in retrieveddatalayerobject)
                    {
                        keymastermodelobject.KeyId = retrieveditems.KeyId;
                        keymastermodelobject.TypeName = retrieveditems.TypeMaster.TypeName;

// Create a New List Of KeyMasterModel //

                       keymastermodellist.Add(keymastermodelobject);
                    }

    // Paged List of KeyMaster Model //

                    IPagedList<KeyMasterModel> IPagedListKeyMasterModel = null; 

                    switch (sortOrder)
                    {

                        case "KeyId":
                            if (sortOrder.Equals(CurrentSort))

                                IPagedListKeyMasterModel = keymastermodellist.OrderByDescending
                                        (m => m.KeyId).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);

                    }

                    return IPagedListKeyMasterModel;

                }
```

Comment: Please cleanup the formatting and try to remove as much code which is not relevant. You can show only 1 or two fields as a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as I understand it:

```
KeyMasterViewModel keyMasterViewModel = new KeyMasterViewModel();
[...]
keyMasterViewModel.pagedkeymodel.pagedkeymaster = KeyMasterModelObject;
```

So here you are using `keyMasterViewModel.pagedkeymodel` and assuming it is not null (because you are trying to assign to a property on it). However KeyMasterViewModel doesn't have a constructor and doesn't set `pagedkeymodel` to anything at declaration so it will default to being null. Hence your problem.

Comment: Exactly ! , Can you please help me how to get over with it

Comment: The way to get round any null reference exception is to not refer to something that is null. This means assigning something to the thing that is null before accessing it or not accessing it if the thing is null. Which one you do is down to you.

Comment: In The PagedListModel defining a constructor like --> public pagedlist(){ IPagedList<Security.Models.KeyMasterModel> pagedkeymaster = null }, would it clear the issue

Comment: You have no class called `pagedlist` that I can see at a glance (another reason why cutting your code down to a minimal reproduction would help). However I'm not sure how setting something to null will help no matter where you do it. Your whole problem is something is null and you don't want it to be. What you need is a constructor in `KeyMasterViewModel` whcih is where the problematic null is to set the pagedkeymodel to an appropriate value (possibly just `new PagedKeyModel ()`).

Comment: pubic keyviewmodel(){ pagedlistmodel= new pagedlistmodel();}  Still It didnt work

Comment: The question linked by John Saunders in comments should tell you everything you need to know about how to fix these sorts of problems. I strongly suggest you go and read that and work out the solution yourself rather than trying to get me to give an exact solution. Amongst other reasons the code in your last comment doesn't seem to correspond to any code shown. My suggestion was a constructor for `KeyMasterViewModel` but your code suggests you are writing a constructor for `keyviewmodel` which doesn't appear in your code.